# rhotoalbum for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Anyone knows about Rhotoalbum : http://rhotoalbum.rubyforge.org/ . This gallery examples looks very good, but in the website isn't good information how to add this gallery to my ruby on rails project. I am beginner in ruby on rails, so could someone help or point to good information source? By the way I am using ruby on rails 3.2.1.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably run Rhotoalbum locally, then store your pictures in public/pictures directory.  Then run Rhotoalbum to create the thumbnails and such.  Add them to your Rails project with Git, then the next time you deploy your Rails app, it will have the pictures available at http://hostname.com/pictures/